# How call method of object when click on checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have project with responses freelancers. When owner of project select freelancer like performer, he click on checkbox response. Afrer click musst calling method project.set_performer. I have following code, after click on checkbox nothing happens.

**Propject.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: projects
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  title          :string
#  description    :text
#  price          :integer
#  location       :string
#  payment        :string
#  anonymity      :boolean
#  category_id    :integer
#  created_at     :datetime         not null
#  updated_at     :datetime         not null
#  price_category :string
#  user_id        :integer
#  performer_id   :integer
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_projects_on_user_id  (user_id)
#
..........................................

def set_performer(id)
  response = Response.find(id)
    project = response.project
    project.update( performer_id: response.freelancer.id )    
end
..........................................
```

**projects/responses.html.erb**

```
<div class="controls">
            <%= check_box_tag 'freelancer_id', @project.set_performer, false, class: 'response', data: { id: "select_freelancer_#{response.freelancer.id}" } %>  
          </div>
```

Comment: you need more data attributes data { remote: true,
    url: your_url_helper}

Comment: and this no call a model method directly.. it will call an action controller and this must call to you model method.